# Calc correct result of 100.1+0.1 as string

Tags: python

If i calc result of some float samples

```
>>> 100.1+0.1
100.19999999999999
```

how to get correct string "100.2"?
I use Py3.2 / Win.

Comment: Is that stray `=` a typo?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, that result is actually correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) to do decimal floating point arithmetic correctly:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('100.1') + decimal.Decimal('0.1')
Decimal('100.2')
>>> str(decimal.Decimal('100.1') + decimal.Decimal('0.1'))
'100.2'
```